# NLTK without X11 on OSX (EPD 64Bit Python)

Tags: python, x11, osx-mountain-lion, nltk, epd-python

I've just installed the latest version of NLTK (2.0.4) from `pip` on OSX 10.8.2. This version os OSX doesn't come with X11 and I like it that way, I don't want to install it. However when I try importing `nltk` in python (2.7.2) an OSX dialog box pops up saying that I need to install X11??

This is probably due to `Tkinter` and the NLTK downloader (or something similar) and probably just a matter of setting some configuration option somewhere to not fall back on X11, I just don't know where to set that option.

There's a [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/nltk/issues/detail?id=79) for `nltk-0.9.5` that the `tk` dependencies are required and this `nltk` can't be run an a server that doesn't have gui libraries, but that issue has been marked as resolved a long time ago.

**Notice** that I'm not trying to run the `nltk` downloader or anything else that should require a gui of any sorts, I'm simply trying to run `import nltk` when the dialog pops up.

The NLTK [install docs](http://nltk.org/install.html) don't give any indication that X11 is required.

So how do I get `nltk` to run on OSX 10.8 without X11?

Comment: Could you please fire an issue at bugtracker (https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues) with more details? Are there any exceptions?

Comment: @MikhailKorobov see update question and solution to the problem below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the problem indeed was `Tkinter`. I'm using the 64bit Mac version of EPDPython and for some reason they've decided to link Tk/Tcl to X11 instead of aqua or cocoa.

OsX 10.8 however comes preinstalled with the correct version of Tk/Tcl and the default python installation `/usr/bin/python.2.7` works out of the box because it uses the correct windowing system for `Tkinter`. The solution is to just remove the wrong libraries from the EPD installation and it'll fall back on the correct system ones.

To try if the suggested fix will work run the system python with

```
$ /usr/bin/python2.7
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 20 2012, 16:23:33) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from Tkinter import *
>>>
```

that should complete without a problem (no dialog boxes), if so you're system python is fine, remove these

```
/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.2/lib/libtcl8.5.dylib
/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.2/lib/libtk8.5.dylib
/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_tkinter.so
```

and python should fall back on the system ones in

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_tkinter.so
```